# How to manage two user tables with single login

Tags: php, mysql

In my application I have two database tables 1.freelancer and 2.Provider with separate user name and password. A freelancer can also be a provider and vice versa. But I need single login for both the users. I am using PHP for this application.

Comment: I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [redit](https://www.reddit.com/)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Question without any efforts!

Comment: I somewhat agree with Jay, though I would be inclined to say it is best to follow some tutorials and self-study, rather than asking broad/vague questions elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

One solution to this would be to move the login information out of the freelancer and provider tables, and then reference the login table from your two tables.

Login:

```
id | username | password
```

Provider:

```
id | user_id (references id from login) | other provider info...
```

Freelancer:

```
id | user_id | other freelancer info ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop both tables and create 3 other tables named `USER`, `USER_ROLE`, `ROLE` that way you can even add more roles if you need to.

```
USER
user_id 
user
```

---

```
USER_ROLE
user_id
role_id
```

---

```
ROLE
role
role_id
```